# Checking for input with space

Tags: android

I've made an offline currency convertor that gets the users input in the EditText section using a TextWatcher  and returns the required ouptut from methods...and I"ve made it an a way that the user cannot insert a "null" value in the EditText section  and then press the convert button by using euro.getText !==null for example.But I don't know how to proceed when the user leaves some space between the input,for instance 29 50.This will make my program to crash.My question what should I use to check for an input with space in order to avoid a program crash?Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program crashes with number format exception. You can do so:

```
try{
    double value = Double.parseDouble(editText.getText().toString());
} catch(NumberFormatException ex){
    Log.e(TAG, "improper number format");
    //show some dialog saying what's the format that should be entered
}
```

You can also go with a regex:

```
String editTextValue = editText.getText().toString();
if(editTextValue.matches("\\d+\\.\\d+")){
    double value = Double.parseDouble(editTextValue);
} else{
    //show dialog saying what should be the format.
}
```

Comment: Your `parseDouble(...)` example is incorrect. `EditText.getText()` returns an `Editable` not a `String`. It should be `Double.parseDouble(editText.getText().toString())`. That also applies to your second example (for regex).

Comment: I keep get this when I try with a regex"Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )"...I"m using matches("\d+\.\d+")

Comment: I think it should be matches("\\d+\\.\\d+")

Comment: yes, I edited it when i edited the editText.toString() thing. Sorry for that too. Yesterday I had to write some regex in ruby and I kinda mixed it up.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually quite easy.
Does your app accept numbers with a comma or a dot? Either way, you can simply replace the `String` by the symbol of you choice by using the following:

```
String unspaced = edittext.getText().toString().replace(' ', '.'); // or ,  depending on what your app uses
```